# Regular expressions in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I am working on a script that utilizes getopts to input a regular expression as part one of the options. The option in question needs to run the expression for the specified file and print out the results to the command line.

I have it saving the expression in a variable, but then I do not know how to properly run the expression from there. Below is the applicable sections of my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=""
sreg=""
search=false


while getopts c:s: flag; do
  case $flag in
    c) #file name
        if ! [ -w "$OPTARG" ]
        then
                echo > "$OPTARG"
        fi
        file="$OPTARG";
;;

    s) #search for contact (use grep)
        search=true
        sreg="$OPTARG";
;;
    ?)
      exit;
;;
  esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ));


if $search
then
       $sreg $file
fi

exit
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues here that http://shellcheck.net/ would catch. `if $search` is horrible practice -- it means you're running any arbitrary command in that string. Better to use `search=0` / `search=1` and `if (( search ))`. Lots of places more quotes are needed. And be sure you know about how bash's built-in regex support works, even though grep sounds like the right thing here (since you're searching through a large, multiline file).

Comment: Also, this question is unnecessarily complicated due to the use of getopts. Why not just ask it as a one-liner with the parts unrelated to your actual problem factored out? See also http://sscce.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Linux, so still figuring out the syntax and such. Ran it through shellcheck and fixed those issues.

Comment: I see how that was too much, tried to cut it down to just the necessary parts, but not enough. Ill take a look at those resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `grep`:

```
grep -e "$sreg" "$file"
```

BTW, you don't need to quote the variables in assignments.

```
file=$OPTARG  # same as file="$OPTARG"
```

Comment: I'd use `-e`, since we don't know what can be in `sreg` and whether it parses as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now! One of my issues was I was trying to pass grep in as part of the variable. Silly me...